# How to OCR the hardcoded Korean subtitles from a movie?

Tags: video, subtitles, ocr, burn-in, korean

I got a Chinese movie called *"Xin li zui (2017)"* with Korean subtitles, burned into it. Or, 'hardcoded'. Now, with an French, Spanish or English subbed movie or just any movie which uses the ABC-alpahbet, I can of course use Subrip and Avidemux to OCR it, and turn it into a .SRT file. But Subrip and Avidemux don't speak nor understand Korean. How do I do this?

Comment: sorry if i upscrewed whomever's edit!!

Comment: You gotta use Tesseract OCR, but even installing it on Windows is HELL HELL HELL ....